# Why did Lord Krishna settle at Dwaraka?

Tags: krishna

Lord Krishna grew up with his people at Mathura (U.P). But why did he move with all his people to Dwaraka? Dwaraka is almost 1300 Kms from Mathura. Was there any logical reason for Krishna to set up his kingdom at Dwaraka?

Answer (score 8):

**`Was there any logical reason for Krishna to set up his kingdom at Dwaraka?`**

**Yes** there is a specific reason behind Lord Krishnas setting up his kingdom at Dwaraka.. Which is discussed in this chapter of [**Shreemad Bhgavatam**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/50/). **SB 10.50: Kṛṣṇa Establishes the City of Dvārakā**

> **Background** – After Shree Krisha killed Kamsa , his two wives “Asti & Prapti” went to their father “Jarasandha” .After hearing the
>   incident Jarasandha got very angry with yadavas. And he decided  to
>   make the earth free of Yadavas. And he then prepared  for war.He
>   seized the Mathura with his 23 Akshhouni warrior force or army . But
>   was defeated by Krishna-Balarama. After that he repeatedly attacked
>   Mathura for next 17 times , but due to the power of Shree Krisha got
>   defeated all the times.
>
> ---
>
> एवं सप्तदशकृत्वस्तावत्यक्शौहिणिबल: |
>  युयुधे मागधो राजा यदुभि:
>   कृष्णपालितै: ||  41 ||
>
> evaṁ saptadaśa-kṛtvas tāvaty akṣauhiṇī-balaḥ  yuyudhe māgadho rājā
>   yadubhiḥ kṛṣṇa-pālitaiḥ 
>  **Seventeen times the King of Magadha met
>   defeat in this very way.** And yet throughout these defeats he fought on
>   with his akṣauhiṇī divisions against the forces of the Yadu dynasty
>   who were protected by Śrī Kṛṣṇa.[**SB 10.50.41**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/50/41)

But when 18th  time the war Between Yadavas and Jarasandha  was about to start ,A another warrior called  **“Kalavayan” also joined Jarasandah** in his fight against Yadavas.  Kalavayana brought  3 core  foreign warriors  and sieged  Mathura . So Krishana and Balarama thought that this time we are facing two very strong armies  and  If we  fought with “kalvayana” this time  , the “Jarasandha” will also attack us and will kill the people of mathura.

> आवयोर्युध्यतोरस्य यद्यगन्ता जरासुत |
>  बन्धून् वधिष्यत्यथवा नेष्यते
>   स्वपुरं बली ||48||
>
> āvayoḥ yudhyator asya yady āgantā jarā-sutaḥ
>  bandhūn haniṣyaty
>   atha vā neṣyate sva-puraṁ balī
>
> “If powerful Jarāsandha comes **while We two are busy fighting
>   Kālayavana, Jarāsandha may kill Our relatives or else take them away
>   to his capital.**[**SB 10.50.47**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/50/47)

And because of this reason Krishna decided to build Safe fort kingdom.

> तस्माददय विधास्यामो दुर्गं द्विपददुर्गमम |
>   तत्र ज्ञातीन् समधाय यवनं घातयामहे ||48||
>
> tasmād adya vidhāsyāmo durgaṁ dvipada-durgamam 
>  tatra jñātīn samādhāya
>   yavanaṁ ghātayāmahe
>
> “Therefore We will immediately construct a **fortress that no human
>   force can penetrate.** **Let Us settle our family members there** and then
>   kill the barbarian king.”[**SB 10.50.48**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/50/48)
>
> ---
>
> इति सम्मन्त्र्य
>   भगवान् दुर्गं द्वादशयोजनं | 
>  अन्त:समुद्रे नगरं कृत्स्नाद्भुतमचिकरत
>   ||49||
>
> iti sammantrya bhagavān durgaṁ dvādaśa-yojanam 
>   antaḥ-samudre nagaraṁ kṛtsnādbhutam acīkarat
>
> After thus discussing the matter with Balarāma, the **Supreme
>   Personality of Godhead had a fortress twelve yojanas in circumference
>   built within the sea. Inside that fort He had a city built containing
>   all kinds of wonderful things.** [**SB 10.50.49**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/50/49)

---

So the logical reason of Shree –Krishna to set up his kingdom at Dwarak was to **safeguard the his people (yadavas) and to protect them from “Kalavayana” and “ Jarasandah”.** And after their departure to Dwaraka ,fighting and killing these two.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mahabharata, it was due to the fear of Jarasandha that he had to settle in Dwarka.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02014.htm

> We also, O king, from fear of Jarasandha, at one time had to leave Mathura and fly to the city of Dwaravati.

Krishna told Yudhisthira that if he wants to perform Rajasuya Yagna, then Jarasandha has to die.

> If, O great king, thou desirest to perform this sacrifice, strive to release the kings confined by Jarasandha, as also to compass his death. O son of the Kuru race, otherwise this undertaking of thine can never be completed. O thou foremost of intelligent men if the Rajasuya is to be performed by thee, you must do this in this way and not otherwise. This, O king, is my view (on the matter).